# Excel VBA MkDir Run Time error

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create a folder at the address that is stored in the cell B6. The address is: H:\jpDesk\Desktop\Test Project

```
Sub SetUpLocalFolder()

Workbooks("Robot Model.xlsm").Activate
LocalPath = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Preparation").Range("B6").Value
Debug.Print LocalPath
If Right(LocalPath, 1) <> "\" Then LocalPath = LocalPath & "\"

'check if the folder is already created
If Len(Dir(""" & LocalPath & """, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
    MkDir """ & LocalPath & """ 'Error shows here
    MsgBox ("The local folder is successfully created.")
End If

End Sub
```

The error shows "runtime error '76'. Path not found" but Debug.Print shows the correct address.
If I change the code into 
    MkDir "H:\jpDesk\Desktop\Test Project", then everything works. Can someone please let me know why?

Comment: No need for """

Comment: I'd highly recommend using the `Scripting.FileSystemObject` instead - it is much more robust than the ancient legacy file handling methods.

Comment: That is right. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Because you don't need the """ & and the & """.

OR that folder already exists.

Comment: Oops that's right. But why? All the online examples have double quotes around the path address.

Comment: @vivi11130704 - The online examples probably say something like `Dir("C:\Temp", vbDirectory)`.  In that case `"C:\Temp"` is a String literal which refers to a memory location containing the characters `C:\Temp`.  In your case you have a String variable called `LocalPath` which refers to a memory location containing characters `C:\Temp`.  So you would replace the literal `"C:\Temp"` in the example with your variable of `LocalPath`.

Comment: I see what you say. Thanks!